# jqm collapsible set causing problems within popup in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile popup, which has a collapsible set within it, and the popup has `overflow-y = auto`.

**SCENARIO A**
When I open the popup *(which builds content in real-time (when the open-popup button is pressed))*, then I open one of the collapsibles within, then click anywhere within the popup, the popup content automatically scrolls.

**SCENARIO B**
If I then close the popup *(which includes an `.empty()` to clear out that dynamically built content)*, and then repeat **scenario A**, the problem does not occur.

**SCENARIO C**
If I open the popup, but do NOT open any of the collapsibles, I can click anywhere without the problem occurring.

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcCcn/), but it Does Not replicate the problem.

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**

**SCENARIO D**
If I do not declare the content divs to be `data-role='collapsible-set/collapsible'`, but rather just drop the content into normal divs, then I do not have the strange scroll artifacts.

Comment: Popup's parent div should be page div.

Comment: Omar, thanks ... I checked and my popup is a direct descendant of a `data-role=page` div ... ... ... also, please note my EDIT. ... thanks, Shannon